# How to get results from function that will query database, and take values from rows as arguments

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse

I have a dataframe and I want to use values from rows to execute a query (on delta lake) and get results in a new column. However in Synapse notebook I always get an error:

> It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063

I have below function:

```
def execute_sql(database, table):
  query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM {database}.{table}"
  result = spark.sql(query).collect()[0][0]
  return result
```

and I am applying it as such (there are many more columns, I am just using two, but want to keep others):

```
execute_sql=udf(execute_sql,StringType())
new_df=input_df.withColumn('TotalCount',execute_sql(col("Database"), col("Table")))
display(new_df)
```

I am trying to avoid complicating and iterate through dataframe with rdd.collect

Comment: You can not use reference spark object in udf. And to execute the sql queries either you need to do collect with for loop or multiprocessing on driver node itself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference the spark object inside a UDF, and you don't want to use `collect`. The only way is to connect to the server and query. Install the package below and restart the cluster:

**databricks-sql-connector**

[image]

Next, obtain the HTTP path and hostname in compute configurations **Advanced options**.

[image]

Next, get the access token in **User settings** **developer** tab.

[image]

Modify your function as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from databricks import sql
import os

DATABRICKS_SERVER_HOSTNAME="https://adb...........azuredatabricks.net/"
DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH="sql/protocolv1/o/34567890/7890789789"
DATABRICKS_TOKEN="dapi.............."

def get_res(db, tb):
    with sql.connect(server_hostname = DATABRICKS_SERVER_HOSTNAME, http_path = DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH, access_token = DATABRICKS_TOKEN) as connection:

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT count(*) FROM {db}.{tb}")
            result = cursor.fetchall()

        # print(result)
        cursor.close()
        return result[0][0]
    
execute_sql = udf(get_res, IntegerType())
```

Next, execute your dataframe statement.

```py
df.withColumn("ts", execute_sql(col("database"), col("tableName"))).display()
```

Output:

| database | tableName | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| default | control_table | 6 |
| default | maxtimestamp | 1 |
| default | student | 6 |
| default | table | 1 |
| default | table_name | 8 |
| default | week_of_5 | 0 |

[image]

Refer below documentation on how to connect to databricks using python.
[Connect Python and pyodbc to Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/pyodbc.html)